# Excel IF functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having an excel issue where I want column A to return the text "OPEN" if there is data in column C however if there is ALSO data in column G I want it to return "CLOSED".

At the same time if there is no data in either column C or G I do not want column A to be populated with anything.

```
Current formula : =IF(COUNT(C14)=1,IF(NOT(OR(C14="<>",G14="")),"CLOSED","OPEN"))
```

See attached photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(AND(C14="",G14=""),"",IF(G14<>"","Closed","Open"))
```

Comment: also make sure you got the updated version.

Comment: i have the updated version as far as i am aware. It just returns FALSE

Comment: then you did not get the latest.  refresh the screen and recopy the formula.